# find intersection point point of 4 (or maybe more) planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, cross-product, plane-geometry, computer-vision

I working on a system with light, cameras and an eye.
I need to find, from the position of the light and camera reflected on the eye, a position inside the eye. In order to do that, I have this formula:

I am in a 3D system, given the formula:
$$((L-C)\times(U-C))\cdot(C_C-C) = 0$$

(here $\times$ represent a cross-product and $\cdot$ a dot product)

I know the position of $L$, $C$ and $U$. I need to find the position of $C_C$.

in order to do that, I have 2 different $C$ and $2$ different $L$ equations like that:

$$((L_0-C_0)\times(U_0-C_0))\cdot(C_C-C_0) = 0$$
$$((L_1-C_0)\times(U_1-C_0))\cdot(C_C-C_0) = 0$$
$$((L_0-C_1)\times(U_2-C_1))\cdot(C_C-C_1) = 0$$
$$((L_1-C_1)\times(U_3-C_1))\cdot(C_C-C_1) = 0$$

How can I isolate the $X_{cc}$,$Y_{cc}$ and $Z_{cc}$ and so find the position of $C_C$ ?

I tried to do it via a substitution and addition methods of the equation but at the end, my $X_{cc}$,$Y_{cc}$ and $Z_{cc}$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), this is almost too messy to read. Thanks.

Comment: it's done. Is it good enough now?

Comment: There are four different "$U$", is that a typo, or do you also know all of them?

Comment: I know all of them. that's the differents reflection of the light of the eye for each camera. I know everything except the CC point. but all the U are different to each other like for the L and the C. (L0 for camera 0 L1 for camera 1, etc)

Comment: I have some difficulty to make sense of your problem/context, but if I understood your problem, you basically have to solve a system of 4 linear equations with 3 unknowns? My algebra is too rusty to figure out whether you have a solution based on the relationships among your coefficients. If there are no solution, rewrite this as $A\times CC=B$. You can then compute $\hat{CC}=(A^tA)^{-1}A^tB$, from memory it gives an approximation when your system is over constrained under some metric I forgot... (but it probably minimizes a least square error)

Comment: thank to you I found what I needed ! Your $\hat{CC}=(A^tA)^{-1}A^tB$ remind me a thesis I read some times before with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you have two equations

$v_1 \cdot (C_c-C_0)=0 $
$v_2 \cdot(C_c-C_0)=0 $ where $v_1,v_2$ and $C_0$ are known

and additional two ones

$v_3 \cdot(C_c-C_1)=0 $
$v_4 \cdot(C_c-C_1)=0 $ where $v_3,v_4$ and $C_1$ are known.

Clearly
$(C_c-C_0)$ is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ so it is of the form $(C_c-C_0) = k(v_1 \times v_2)=k v_{12}$  where $k$ is some unknown scalar 
and
  $(C_c-C_1)$ is orthogonal to both $v_3$ and $v_4$ so it is of the form $(C_c-C_1)=l(v_3 \times v_4)=l v_{34}$ where $l$ is some unknown scalar.

So in fact you have two straight line equations $C_c=C_0+k v_{12} $  and $C_c=C_1+l v_{34} $.

Comparing both equations we can obtain unknown $k,l$ and consequently $C_c$,
however it would be a case only under condition that all data are perfectly geometrically accurate and both lines intersect at one point (namely $C_c$).

In the case of more experimental data probably these two lines don't intersect.

In this case **the midpoint of the segment which is perpendicular  to both lines** will be the best solution of the problem. Note that this segment is unique for skew lines in 3D space.

This segment has direction $v_s=( v_{12}\times v_{34} )$ and equation embracing it $C_0-C_1= k_sv_{12}+l_sv_{34}+m_sv_s$, where we have three unknown $k_s \  ,l_s, \ m_s$ which can be accurately calculated from the 3-dimensional vector equation above. It can be transformed further into matrix form

$C_0-C_1= [v_{12} \  \ v_{34} \ \   v_s][k_s \ \   l_s \   \ m_s]^T$

$ [k_s \ \   l_s  \ \  m_s]^T=[v_{12} \  \ v_{34} \ \   v_s]^{-1}(C_0-C_1)  $

Of course vectors $v_s, \  v_{34}, \ v_{12}$ should be linearly independent which, I hope, is guaranteed under conditions of the experiment.

Having this you should easily calculate the searched midpoint which can be regarded as $C_c$.